# Does run mongoskin only with mongodb version 1.4 and older?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoskin

I'm trying to understand nodejs, express and mongodb
I'm running mongodb v 2.0.6 and latest nodejs and express
and trying to connect express application with mongodb through mongoskin.
the problem is:

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package mongodb does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer mongoskin@1.4.13 wants mongodb@~1.4
```

Does it mean that mongoskin can work only with mongodb v 1.4? This version is to old as for me (current is 3)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's expecting version 1.4 of the MongoDB *driver*, not the database.

You should remove the 2.0.6 version of the driver, as `mongoskin` doesn't work with that yet ([issue](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin/issues/160)), and install the 1.4 version instead:

```
$ npm uninstall mongodb
$ npm install mongodb@~1.4 [--save]
$ npm install mongoskin [--save]
```

(however, I'm not sure if the 1.4 driver works properly with 3.x databases)

Comment: thank you. I have already done it.
Special thank you for issue number.