# Cannot start node server, issue with mongodb database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to follow this [tutorial](https://blog.udemy.com/node-js-tutorial/#0), I cannot run the node server because of this error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
>       at makeSkinClass

Here is my path :

> echo $PATH
>   /usr/local/mysql/bin:/mongodb/bin:Users/Empon/npm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin

I figured out that `-g` never works in my Terminal, so I tried to add the paths to the PATH permanently, I added mongodb to both bashrc, and bash_profile.

Then I did `npm install -g mongodb`, I had this :

> mongodb-core@1.2.32 requires a peer of kerberos@~0.0 but none was
>   installed.

So I added `npm install --save kerberos mongodb` and the result was :

> npm WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not
>   running remove bson@0.4.21 node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson npm
>   WARN skippingAction Module is inside a symlinked module: not running
>   remove core-util-is@1.0.2

Now, in my Node project, I do : `node bin/www` to start the server (I tried node app.js, with "app.js" in the config file, but it did not work, so I let `./bin/www`), and the url is : `http://localhost:3000/api/videos`.

Would you know what is wrong?

---

EDIT:
I got it working, with these manipulations : installing an older version of mongodb and changing a line in a config file :

[Does run mongoskin only with mongodb version 1.4 and older?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29804321/does-run-mongoskin-only-with-mongodb-version-1-4-and-older)

[Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' } js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651028/cannot-find-module-build-release-bson-code-module-not-found-js-bson)

I am almost there, the url to the port works fine (http://localhost:3000/), but not the one for mongodb (http://localhost:3000/api/videos), the error is :

> Error: Not Found
>       at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/workspace/Vidzy/app.js:32:13
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/workspace/Vidzy/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at trim_prefix (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/workspace/Vidzy/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)

And my code is :

```
//in routes/video.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/vidzy');

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    var collection = db.get('videos');
    collection.find({}, function(err, videos){
       if (err) throw err;
       res.json(videos);
    });
});
module.exports = router;


//in app.js
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});
```

The Terminal is connected to mongoDB :

> I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017

Would someone know why I get a 404, and how to debug this?

Comment: This seems like you are missing a required module. Perhaps re-run `npm install mongoskin --save` in the app directory to be sure. Don't forget to use `--save` or `--save-dev` when you are installing dependencies.

Comment: Try to follow this solution https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin/issues/153#issuecomment-85740639

Comment: @PeteGarafano thanks, I found a solution with the 2 urls I posted, but my page does not work yet, could you have a look at my edit?

Comment: @Maxali thanks, same as for Pete, I found a solution with the 2 urls I posted, but my page does not work yet, could you have a look at my edit?

Comment: I think this `http://localhost:3000/api/videos` is *MongoDB* REST interface. If so, its not running the same port `3000` as `express`. Try port `28017` and restart `mongod` with `--rest` option.

Comment: @Maxali no I made a mistake, I wrote "app" instead of "api" in my route... now it is working fine. Thank you very much for your help anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem : the version of mongodb was incorrect, and so was the version of mongoskin. I don't know much about why the error occured, but setting the project with mongodb 1.4 and mongoskin 1.3 works fine.

`npm install mongoskin@1.3.20 --save`

and

`$ npm install mongodb@~1.4 --save`

source: [Does run mongoskin only with mongodb version 1.4 and older?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29804321/does-run-mongoskin-only-with-mongodb-version-1-4-and-older)

---

In case something is wrong with the debug file, here is the change to make :

replace :
`bson = require('../build/Release/bson');`

with :
`bson = require('../browser_build/bson');`

in :

> npm module mongodb
>   ..node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson\ext\index.js

source : [Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' } js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651028/cannot-find-module-build-release-bson-code-module-not-found-js-bson)